# How to convert .mp3 files to .bin files in android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is it possible to convert any audio file to .bin in android?If so is will the .bin files be played in android or using android NDK?

Comment: **Please! google "android audio to binary converter"** and you may get list of useful results.

Comment: Hi RDC thanks for your suggestion .I'm trying to play an audio file in Android NDK.I found one sample code from Git" github.com/waywardgeek/sonic-ndk".This sample is only playing ".bin files". I want to make my mp3 file to be played .so i want to know how to convert mp3 to .bin .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java library [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) to decode mp3 files. Alternatively, you can use a native library if you want it to go faster, but the implementation is quite a lot harder. I know mpg123 works on Android.

However, if you just want to play the mp3 file, why don't you just play it with [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)?